# Nesting content into into a child element

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I want to nest the content of a parent element inside a child element.

```
<polymer-element name="parent-form" noscript>
    <template>

        <child-form>
            <content></content>
        </child-form>

    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Then I want to use the component like this.

```
<parent-form>
    <input type="text"/>
</parent-form>
```

With the expectation that input would be inside the 'child-form'.

The actual result of this in Chrome is that the content is placed before the 'child-form' and the 'child-form' has no content.

Can I nest content like this inside custom child elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, see http://jsbin.com/dotemo/11/edit. Are you sure you've imported your child element?

You can use this bookmarklet to find unregistered elements in general - https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/debugging.html#unregistered-element-bookmarklet

Comment: is right, you are on the right track but you miss one template: you have two components and a single template. That way you miss a *content* tag to get the result you are waiting for...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here, can you elaborate?

Comment: The JSBin example works as expected. I'm not sure what I was doing incorrectly; it may have been a missing template as suggested by @bdulac. I ended up changing things to use inheritance which was actually a better solution anyway.

Comment: In your "parent-form" template, the content tag is nested in a "child-form" element. But without a "child-form" template, the browser will ignore that element as it will consider it undefined. If you inspect your page and compare it with the JSBin page, Firefox will help you to understand. As Firefox (unlinke Chrome and Opera) uses the polyfill it does not hide the shadow DOM while inspecting and shows that in the JSBIN the "parent-form" istelf is properly rendered with a "child-form" element as in your document.

Comment: But without a "child-form" template, there is no shadow DOM for this component to introduce your content tag. As a consequence, you never have the input.